# Is there a Unity launcher progress bar for Transmission?

Tags: unity, icons, downloads, bittorrent, transmission

Like UnityFox (and the Nautilus launcher), is there a way to have Transmission's launcher show the progress of a download?

Comment: 12.04 has this by default. Can't find an 11.10 version though I could have sworn I has this installed on my system :(((

Comment: By default? I have 12.04 and don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be useful for you: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/integrate-transmission-with-unity.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This doesn't work for 12.04.